# Creating a Kubernetes Service with Pulumi up results in error Could not create watcher for Endpoint objects associated with Service

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

I'm trying to use Pulumi to create a Deployment with a linked Service in a Kubesail cluster.  The Deployment is created fine but when Pulumi tries to create the Service an error is returned:

```
kubernetes:core:Service (service):
    error: Plan apply failed: resource service was not successfully created by the Kubernetes API server : Could not create watcher for Endpoint objects associated with Service "service": unknown
```

The Service is correctly created in Kubesail and the error seems to be glaringly obvious that it can't do Pulumi's neat monitoring but the `unknown` error isn't so neat!

What might be being denied on the Kubernetes cluster such that Pulumi can't do the monitoring that would be different between a Deployment and a Service?  Is there a way to skip the watching that I missed in the docs to get me past this?

Comment: i dont think there was a way to skip watching last time i checked, try asking on their slack channel or raising an issue

Comment: Check your RBAC roles? That could cause it to fail the watch.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little into the Pulumi source code and found the resource kinds it uses to track and used `kubectl auth can-i` and low and behold watching an endpoint is currently denied but watching replicaSets and the service themselves is not.